# Store Text into an Scalar within If / Else Statement - Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, built-in

I want to accomplish the following into Robot Framework

I want to store a Text from an Element `xpath://*[@id="plsAttachGrid_0_1"]`into a Scalar `${name3}`, however, the Element is not always available on the web page, therefore, I need to run a IF/ELSE statement in order to avoid an Error when the Element is not available

My idea was the following:

```
${countt2}=    Get Element Count    xpath://*[@id="plsAttachGrid_0_1"]
Run Keyword If    ${countt2}>0    
${name3}=    Get Text    xpath://*[@id="plsAttachGrid_0_1"]
ELSE    LOG    NO_FILE
```

However, I have learnt It is not possible to store into a Scalar inside `Run Keyword If`, since it is expecting  a `Keyword`.

Therefore, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Are you aware of the keyword named [Set variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A keyword inside `Run Keyword If` can return a value that propagates up - e.g. can be assigned to a variable placed before the `Run Keyword If`; so in your case:

```
${name3}=    Run Keyword If    ${countt2}>0        Get Text    xpath://*[@id="plsAttachGrid_0_1"]
```

So now `${name3}` will have the return value of `Get Text` when `${countt2}>0`.
What will its value be if the condition is not met? It'll be `None` (the data type, not a string), as the variable is now declared, but not explicitly defined.

You can set it to a different value in this case, to handle it easier later in the code:

```
${name3}=    Run Keyword If    ${countt2}>0        Get Text    xpath://*[@id="plsAttachGrid_0_1"]
                 ...           ELSE                Set Variable     not_set  # or ${0}, or any other value you need for ${countt2}<=0
```